# Google spreadsheet formula to resolve string as a cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

Using google spreadsheets is there a way to evaluate a cell value as the row in a lookup operation? For example rather than =D2 to grab the value of D2, I want to evaluate the value of a cell and use it as the row to lookup another cell.  I've looked at the google spreadsheet formula documentation and haven't been able to find a solution.

The below pseudocode illustrates what I'm trying to do.

```
        A     B    C    D
    1         D
    2       =[B1]2     10
    3       =[B1]3      9
    4       =[B1]4      8
```

Given the value of B1 is "D" I want cells B2, B3, and B4 to resolve to 10, 9, and 8 respectively.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might be looking for something like this:

`=INDIRECT(INDEX(B$1;1;1)&ROW())`

1. the `INDEX(B$1;1;1)` gets content of B1 cell (the 1;1 is obligatory parameter, since you can feed INDEX with range and means: *1st row in range;1st column in range* which is **D**
2. `ROW()` returns current row number, be it **2, 3** etc.
3. & concatenates both value, so the result is processed like **"D" & "2"** => **"D2"**
4. `INDIRECT(reference)` returns reference to a cell or an area (in text form) for which to return the contents.

see https://support.google.com/drive/table/25273?hl=en

Still, depending on what is the original problem, there might be better solutions. Above one is just straightforward answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Bearing in mind the correctness and helpfulness of PsychoFish's advice on the use of `INDEX()` with `INDIRECT()`, and on the limited usefulness of any one solution for all problems, I think the following formula will work as well in this particular case:

```
=INDIRECT(B$1&Row())
```

Comment: For case at hand simpler syntax always helps to get the job done more quickly. I just wanted illustrate usage of INDEX and INDIRECT combination in case of more general problem would need to be solved.